making a variable update in an API Loop
firstly i am very new to python
the issue i get is the in the output url, the "limit" variable doesn't update
on the second loop it shows : https://website.com/table1/?key=xxxx&limit=0,+100 when i want it to show https://website.com/table1/?key=xxxx&limit=100,+100
i can see the limit variable is incrementing by 100 but it is just not passing it through to the api url
import requests
import json
import csv
import pandas as pd
import os
 
os.remove('ladder.csv')
os.remove('ladder.json')
 
 
# Define the base URL and parameters
base_url = 'https://website.com/table1/?key=xxxx'
 
query_params = ",+"
limit = 0
offset = 100
full_url = f'{base_url}{limit}{query_params}{offset}'
 
 
# Function to fetch data from the API
def fetch_data(full_url):
    response = requests.get(full_url)
    print (response.url)
 
    print (offset)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        return response.json()
    else:
        print(f"Error: {response.status_code}")
        print("Response content:", response.content)
        return None
 
# Initialize variables
all_data = []
has_more_data = True
     
# Loop to fetch data with pagination
while has_more_data:
    # Fetch data
    data = fetch_data(full_url)
     
    if data:
        # Debug: Print the response structure
         
        print(limit,offset)
         
        # Check if 'results' key exists in the response
        if 'ranking' in data:
            # Process the data (example: extend the all_data list with new records)
            all_data.extend(data['ranking'])
             
            
            # Check if there is more data to fetch
            if offset >= 1000:
                    has_more_data = False
            else:
 
                if len(data['ranking']) < limit:
                  has_more_data = False
                 
                else:
                # Update the offset for the next request
                  limit += offset
        else:
            print("Key 'ranking' not found in the response")
            has_more_data = False
             
    else:
        has_more_data = False
         
# Example: Save all data to a JSON file
with open('ladder.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(all_data, f, indent=4)
 
print("Data fetching complete. Total records fetched:", len(all_data))
 
with open('ladder.json', encoding='utf-8') as inputfile:
    df = pd.read_json(inputfile)
 
df.to_csv('ladder.csv', encoding='utf-8', index=False)


You forgot to re-create full_url after modifying your variables.

where in the loop would i put the "full_url"?

What about just before using it??

Your issue seems to be with how the full_url variable is constructed inside the loop. The full_url is being set before the loop starts and is not updated within the loop, so the updated limit value isn't being used in subsequent requests.

where in the loop would i put the "full_url"?

Remove the url from the where you have defined and add it here.
# Loop to fetch data with pagination  while has_more_data:            # Fetch data            full_url = f'{base_url}&limit={limit}{query_params}{offset}'       data = fetch_data(full_url)

The issue in your code is that the full_url variable is not being updated within the loop. Currently, full_url is defined before the loop and never updated inside it, which is why the limit parameter doesn't change in subsequent requests.
To fix this, you need to update full_url within the loop, after updating the limit and offset values

where in the loop would i put the "full_url"?

This is the problem:
full_url = f'{base_url}{limit}{query_params}{offset}'

You seem to view this as an ongoing formula that will keep full_url up to date as its component parts change.
That's not how Python works.
The value of full_url is assigned ONCE, and that's the end of it.  Changing offset later on has no effect.
You need to reassign full_url every time through the loop.
Or you could change full_url to be a function that assembles and returns the url string fresh every time when it is called.

you mention a function, how is this done?
or where in the loop would i put the "full_url"?
